# Visual Report for Code Coverage in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

In rails I would use a gem called [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) which would generate a nice html page after tests ran which would highlight where your tests are hitting(and give the percentage covered). Is there anything that can do this in Django?

Picture for reference as to what I want(This is simplecov):

[image: example simplecov rendering]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

coverage.py has an a command, `coverage html`, which generates html pages very similar to your screenshot.  Here's an example from some of my own recent code:
[image]

There is documentation for how to integrate coverage into your Django testing tools at [The Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#integration-with-coverage-py).

Comment: Ohh nice. All the examples I found for the html feature in coverage.py showed just a html version of what you would see in Terminal. Interesting they would show the less-pretty representation over this.